# How can I call JavaScript function in Phonegap through the webview?

Tags: javascript, cordova, webview

I have developed a phonegap application using the concept of webview.Then, i defined a function in index.js that i want to call it after opening my website through the application(as a webview).
When i tested my application,it doesn't call the function 'AppelPG' and i don't know how i should do without writing any native code.
How can I call this Javascript function in my webview?

```
var app = {
    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function() {
      alert("initialisation de l'application!");
        // window.location.href = "http://mywebsite.com";
        window.open('http://mywebsite.com', '_self ', 'location=yes');
        this.bindEvents();
    },

    AppelPG: function(){
        alert("Appel fonction définie dans l'application!");
    }
    // Bind Event Listeners
    //
    // Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
    // 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },
}
```

Comment: i think you've to use the plugin for inAppBrowser

Comment: i have used this plugin but when i opened the new Window, it doesn't call any function defined in the body of the application..Have you another solution please?